Does the definition of mixing time work for general non-Markovian processes?
A definition of the mixing time for Markov chains is given by
\begin{equation}
\tau_{\text{mix}}\equiv\inf{\{t>0: \sup_i\left\vert \frac{\boldsymbol{p}(t|p_j(0)=\delta_{ij})}{\boldsymbol{\pi}}-\mathbb{I}\right \vert_2 \}\leq\frac{1}{e}},
\end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ is the stationary distribution, $\boldsymbol{p}(t|p_j(0)=\delta_{ij})$ is the probability distribution at time $t$ given that the initial distribution is a delta distribution $p_j(0)=\delta_{ij}$ and $\mathbb{I}$ is the unit vector. I think the maximization over all the initial state assure that the definition can be applied to any stochastic processes, not limited to Markov chain whose mixing behavior is exponential (If there is no maximization over initial states in the definition, then it cannot be applied to non-exponential mixing process. Because that will lead to different mixing times for different initial states).
However, I have not seen any papers focusing on the mixing time of non-Markovian processes. It seems that mixing time is a concept only for Markov chains. So, are there any problems to apply this definition to non-Markovian processes? Certaintly, we should assume that there is at least one invariant measure for the interested non-Markovian process. Then, can we apply this definition to the invariant measure of that non-Markovian process?
